# When collapsing an accordion, the borders disappear in that duration, how can the borders be visible while the accordion is being collapsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When the accordion is being collapsed, I noticed that the borders are not showing in that duration. For example, when the accordion is expanded we see the borders while it is expanding. Can this also be done while the accordion is being collapsed?
Is there a way to show the borders while the accordion is being collapsed? Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/cfp1Lmob/1/

```
 .accordion-toggle {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;

        }

        .accordion-toggle:hover {
            background-color: #dad9d6;

        }


        .collapse {
            padding: 0 18px;
            max-height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            transition: max-height 1.0s;
            margin-bottom: -4px;
        }

        .collapsed + .collapse {
          border-left: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
          border-right: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
          border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1
        }

        .collapse p {
            padding-top: 13px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying the border using the selector `.collapsed + .collapse` – but your trigger element gets that `collapsed` class taken away when the item gets collapsed, so the border disappears.

Apply the border using a selector that matches in both cases - using the `accordion-toggle` class, that is present in both states:

```
.accordion-toggle + .collapse {
    border-left: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-right: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f1f1f1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nyujfwg3/

But this way, the bottom border will still be visible when the element is collapsed. If you want to avoid that as well, you either need to take it away once the transition ends; or apply it to an element inside of `.collapse` instead.